# How do you structure a Bing Cogntivie Services API News request?

Tags: python-3.x, bing, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I am currently writing an application that uses the Bing Cognitive Services search API and I am trying to scrape the news results in particular and am running into some problems

For a normal search, the request is structured pretty simply:

```
def bing_search(query):

    url = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search'

    payload = {'q': query, 'freshness': 'week', 'mkt': 'en-us'}

    headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'API KEY', 'X-MSEdge-ClientID': ''}

    r = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)

    return r.json()
```

This works perfectly and returns the correct results when I add a query in, however thats just for normal search.

When I try and use the news search, and I change the url variable to this as the documentation suggests:

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news?
```

However when I run this and insert a query, it returns a json which contains only the top news stories of the day, and not relevant at all to the query I added.

Am I structuring the url correctly? I would be very grateful if anyone could help me out to structure the request so it returns the correct results.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's useful to think of news-search as having **2 modes of operation**:

- **Categorical/Trending.** Format is:

  https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news?category=FOO_CATEGORY&...&mkt=en-us&...
- **Query-based.** Format is:

  https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search?q=FOO_QUERY&...

*To enter a `q=...` param in a news search you'll need to use that second "Query-based" format.*

*If you want to do a categorical search, you'll need to specify either `en-US` or `en-GB` in the `mkt` param, then replace `FOO_CATEGORY` with one of the following:*

```
NEWS_CATEGORIES_US = (
    'Business',
    'Entertainment',
    'Entertainment_MovieAndTV',
    'Entertainment_Music',
    'Health',
    'Politics',
    'ScienceAndTechnology',
    'Science',
    'Technology',
    'Sports',
    'Sports_Golf',
    'Sports_MLB',
    'Sports_NBA',
    'Sports_NFL',
    'Sports_NHL',
    'Sports_Soccer',
    'Sports_Tennis',
    'Sports_CFB',
    'Sports_CBB',
    'US',
    'US_Northeast',
    'US_South',
    'US_Midwest',
    'US_West',
    'World',
    'World_Africa',
    'World_Americas',
    'World_Asia',
    'World_Europe',
    'World_MiddleEast',
)
NEWS_CATEGORIES_GB = (
    'Business',
    'Entertainment',
    'Health',
    'Politics',
    'ScienceAndTechnology',
    'Sports',
    'UK',
    'World',
)
```

If you're still having trouble, here's a simple python 2.7 interface: https://github.com/rtruxal/bingapipy